# Element looks like in the map, but it's not in the map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have the following snippet of the code:

```
map<string, map<string,size_t> >  occurence_counts;
.... initialize map from a file....
for(const auto & a: occurence_counts)
     cout << a.first   << "\n";

cout << occurence_counts.count("sam") << "\n";
```

Output is:

```
sam
jake
cate
0
```

What?! When I output the keys, "sam" is there , but count of "sam" is 0?? Can anybody help me understand? Also when I do occurence_counts["sam"] , it returns nothing as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there's some whitespace in `sam`? Assuming that those types are `std::map` and `std::string`. Try outputting `a.first.size()` and ensure that it's `3`.

Comment: It will probably be helpful to log the length of the strings, like this `cout << "\"" << a.first  << "\" len=" << a.first.size() << endl;`. In the real program, is there any code between the code that traverses the map and the code that checks the count? Are they in the same function?

Comment: Just use a debugger, please

Answer (score 1):

If you print the component characters of each key, as hex-pairs, then you can see what is *actually* stored. When you just output the string in its human-readable form, you mask trailing whitespaces and other such anomalies that, clearly, exist in this case.